# PHP solution to sanitize user formatted input and make XHTML Strict compliant

Tags: php, xhtml, string, sanitization

What are best solutions for making user formatted input

1. safe + script/flash free
2. XHTML Strict compliant

[Tidy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiptidy.html) converts HTML to XHTML Strict.  Any similar/alternative options that does this plus sanitizes and removes embedded scripts and flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I tend to use [htmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php